Trouble reusing java records in Jooq
I'm using a multiset in the context of a larger query. Something along these lines :
multiset(
    select(DOCUMENT.ID, DOCUMENT.NAME)
        .from(DOCUMENT)
        .innerJoin(PROJECT_DOCUMENTS)
        .on(PROJECT_DOCUMENTS.DOCUMENT_ID.eq(DOCUMENT.ID))
        .where(PROJECT_DOCUMENTS.PROJECT_ID.eq(PROJECT.ID))
).as("documents")
    .convertFrom(r -> r.collect(intoSet(mapping(ProjectDocument::new))));

ProjectDocument is a Java record
public record ProjectDocument(Long id, String name, Long count) {
    public ProjectDocument(Long id, String name) {
        this(id, name, null);
    }
}

As you can see it has two constructors as I want to use it in different scenarios.
However when I do this Java is not happy:
java: method collect in interface org.jooq.Result<R> cannot be applied to given types;
  required: java.util.stream.Collector<? super org.jooq.Record2<java.lang.Long,java.lang.String>,A,X>
  found:    java.util.stream.Collector<org.jooq.Record3<java.lang.Object,java.lang.Object,java.lang.Object>,capture#1 of ?,java.util.Set<java.lang.Object>>
  reason: inference variable R has incompatible bounds
    upper bounds: org.jooq.Record,org.jooq.Record3<T1,T2,T3>,R
    lower bounds: org.jooq.Record2<java.lang.Long,java.lang.String>

If I change the record to only have the id & name properties, it works fine.
Any ideas?
Thanks

This isn't specific to jOOQ, it's just that with the overloaded record constructor, type inference will no longer work for the constructor reference ProjectDocument::new. To work around this, just use a lambda instead:
mapping((id, name) -> new ProjectDocument(id, name))

Or, alternatively, use a static factory method:
public record ProjectDocument(Long id, String name, Long count) {
    public static ProjectDocument create(Long id, String name) {
        return new ProjectDocument(id, name, null);
    }
}

And then:
mapping(ProjectDocument::create)

